# How to traverse an array with predefined order in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, traversal

For a array of m*n, say

```
{{a, b, c},  
{d, e, f},  
{g, h, i}}
```

What's the best practice way to traverse it in orders like a,b,c,f,i,h,g,d,(clockwise)?

Any external link on related tricks are warmly welcome.

Comment: What have you tried? You haven't supplied very much information and you are asking us to do the work for you. That's not what this site is for. - You could have simply done a search on google similar to: "Reorder an array" if you wanted a link.

Comment: What happened to poor old 'e'?  It's cruel to orphan data at this time of year.

Comment: @Lemony-Andrew OK. How to traverse the array in clockwise order in one for loop. That's my question. I already said, "best practice" as obviously there is a not-so-elegant way to do that.

Comment: Donkey: "Are we there yet?".  Shrek: "No". Donkey: "Are we there yet?". Shrek: "No". Donkey: "Are we there yet?". Shrek: "Yes, so I'm turning right".

Answer (score 2):

Donkey: "Are we there yet?". Shrek: "No". Donkey: "Are we there yet?". Shrek: "No". Donkey: "Are we there yet?". Shrek: "Yes, so I'm turning right".  Repeat until you reach Far, Far Away.

Four enums, EdirRight,EdrDown,EdrLeft,EdrUp, a 'currentDirection' var of that type, a boolean map for 'visited before'.

Case switch on currentDirection inside a do/while loop.  In each case, calculate the next position, see if it's been visited before or is out-of-bounds. If visited before, you are done. If out-of-bounds, set currentDirection to the next clockwise direction and recalculate next position.

Spiralling in to the centre should be a small extension - just recheck 'visited before' after turning.

Answer (score 0):

Just think about what you need to do in order to do one circle. Starting at top left corner, you go m elements to the right, then n-1 elements down, m-1 elements to the left, n-2 elements top, m-2 elements to the right and so on.

Comment: yes. that's a way. But according to your wording, it requires 4 for-loops.

Comment: @Introom it was the first solution that popped to my mind :-). There probably is something more efficient, but 4-loop solution is probably the easiest.